# How to set authentication information into the supertest request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I'm trying to create tests for our Web API Application but it's getting really hard behind work's firewall/proxy/any other block. The API is based on express and MongoDB. For testing, I'm using mocha, chai and supertest. I have a `server.js` application which does the following:

```
const server = express();

function start() {
    process.env.NO_PROXY = '*';
    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname +'/key.pem', "utf8"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert.pem', "utf8"),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ca.pem', "utf8"),
        passphrase: process.env.PASSPHRASE,
        secureProtocol: "TLSv1_2_method"
    };

    /** Create SSO authentication here **/

    server.use(routes);

    Q.allSettled(promises).then(
        function (results) {
            /** More code **/
            var https_server = https.createServer(options, server);
            /** More code **/
        }
    );
}

start();

// Export for testing
module.exports = server;
```

Note that in the `Create SSO authentication here` we set our company's sso (by `server.use` and `server.get`). The way we run the application is by running:

```
node server.js <port_number> (dev | prod) [verbose]
```

In the `test.js` I have:

```
const server = require('../server.js');

describe('Test API', function () {
    describe('Test Health Check', function() {
        it('should return status 302 for healthcheck', function(done) {
        this.timeout(50000);
        request(server)
            .get('/healthcheck')
            .end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(res.text);
                done();
            });
        });

    });
});
```

I run `/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --exit`, print the `res.text` and it says:

```
Found. Redirecting to <WORK'S-FIRWALL-DOMAIN/URL>
```

So I guess that I need to use the `redirects(1)` so:

```
            .get('/healthcheck').redirects(1)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(res.text);
                done();
            });
```

But I get `undefined`. After some more research over SO I found out that I should use `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` at the start of the `test.js` file. But then I get (changed to `console.log(res.error)` so it will be a more readable error):

```
   { Error: cannot GET /api/v1/Windows/Auth?redirectUrl=<URL> (401)
    at Response.toError (/api_app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/response.js:94:15)
    at ResponseBase._setStatusProperties (/api_app/node_modules/superagent/lib/response-base.js:123:16)
    at new Response (/api_app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/response.js:41:8)
    at Test.Request._emitResponse (/api_app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:752:20)
    at parser (/api_app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:916:38)
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (/api_app/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:19:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
     status: 401,
     text: '{\r\n  "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."\r\n}',
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/api/v1/Windows/Auth?redirectUrl=<URL>' },
```

When I go to our production instance, click the Chrome's dev tools and check the `initiator` of the `networks`, I see that the URL is making **4** redirections:

```
[Requested-URL] -> [Auth-URL] -> [Validsso-URL] ->[Requested-URL]
```

So I tried to change to `redirects(4)` (after checking `2`, `3` and even `5`) but got the same error for all of the tries.

I really have no idea why it happens and how to solve it. Tried to go through all of the supertest's github issues but could not find the reason. I understand that I need the SSL certificate in order to connect to the website, but I could not find out way to pass the `pem` files to the `request(server)`. I also tried to install and use the `supertest-proxy` (`request(server).proxy(PROXY)`) but it didn't help. Also I don't think it's a proxy issue, rather a authentication issue. furthermore, I don't understand why it tried to enter `/api/v1/Windows/Auth?redirectUrl=<URL>` (without `https`). Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**: I have removed the SSO part and it works without it (and even without redirects). I would like to make it work with SSO. What could I miss?

Comment: Try that flow in your browser, and I'll bet you'll see some cookies being set. If that's what it's using for auth, set a `cookie` header in your supertest request.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for the quick response. It does set cookies. Shouldn't it set them automatically in the test's http GET request? If not, should I set them manually? how?

Comment: You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest-session; that seems to do some cookie persistence across requests.

Comment: @Jacob Ok I tried it but got the same error. From the docs: `By default the underlying supertest agent will still determine the CookieAccessInfo from the URL` so I believe it should set the cookies.

Comment: Check the responses to see if a `set-cookie` header is being sent. After your script does a successful login, that should be set.

Comment: @Jacob It does set a cookie (tried to remove all and check out the new one on refresh). It contains: `Name=connect.sid`, `Domain=<Domain>`, `Path=/` and `Content` which contains some complicated string (which changes). I tried to set `var cookieAccess = { domain: '<Domain>', path: '/', secure: true, script: true, };` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Is the URL that reads the cookie on the same domain as the cookie's domain? You'll want to check whether the cookie is getting passed to subsequent requests.

Comment: Without redication, `res` prints `[ 'connect.sid=s%3Ad4BB7b7WfBzaM8oWeP8KrX_Oj6FA1TK_.hURU5FHnA9wZmwsAhN0POKKUsWqgHWvb7LkX%2FdBJOla; Path=/; HttpOnly' ],` in the `set-cookie` of `headers`. But when I use `redirect(1)` it does not contain any cookies.

Comment: Is it redirecting to the same domain so that the cookies can be sent once redirected as well?

Comment: @Jacob It's being generated by the SSO Node modules.  Basically, from the dev tools, I can see it does the following chain: `[Requested-URL] -> [Auth-URL] -> [Validsso-URL] ->[Requested-URL]` where second and third urls are not mine. I guess the cookie is need so only developers from the company can connect.

Comment: Not really what I was asking. In order for the cookies generated by the SSO URL to be carried over to `Requested-URL`, the domain has to be the same as the cookie domain, otherwise `Request-URL` won't receive any and you'll continue getting a 401.